# Facebook iOS SDK Feed Dialog Confirmation Buttons With Strange Language

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-wall

My iOS native App is using the Facebook Feed Dialog to post to user's wall.
But the dialog buttons are in unknown language instead of English. See the screen shots below:

"Ghairi" "Sambaza"?

How to I force the buttons to English?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a user report the same issue. Looks like it's a problem on Facebook's side:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/407246299295529?browse=search_4fa410ea79db26337556383